# Wrong http request in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I develop web-app on Angular 2. The Angular-code:

```
class RouteService { 
    private url : string = 'http://gbsapod/sapodbridge/getRoute?';

    constructor(private http:Http) {    }

     get(cont, foot, out_station_code, dest_station_code, out_country_code, dest_country_code,  special_marks_code, dispatch_type : string): Observable<Route> {
    let buf_url_ : string = this.url;

    // добавление параметров
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "cont=" + cont; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&foot=" + foot; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&outstationcode=" + out_station_code; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&deststationcode=" + dest_station_code; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&outcountrycode=" + out_country_code; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&destcountrycode=" + dest_country_code; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&specialmarkscode=" + special_marks_code; 
    buf_url_ = buf_url_ + "&dispatchtype=" + dispatch_type; 

    return this.http.get(buf_url_, options ).map((resp:Response)=>{ let r =    
    resp.json() as Route; return r;});
```

Backend is servlet under Apache Tomcat. The servlet source:

```
  public class getRoute extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response. setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String host = "gcsapod";
    String port = "2080";
    String in_login = null;
    String in_password = null;
    boolean isRMIHttp = false;

    in_login = request.getParameter("login");
    in_password = request.getParameter("password");

    LogonInfo log = Session.createSession(host, port, in_login, Password.getEncryptedPassword(in_password, false, 0), isRMIHttp);
    DistanceService ds = new DistanceService();
    ds.in_kol_kont = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cont"));// 0
    ds.in_futov = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("foot")); //0
    ds.in_st_otprav = request.getParameter("outstationcode"); //150000
    ds.in_st_nazn = request.getParameter("deststationcode");  //320204
    ds.in_str_otprav = request.getParameter("outcountrycode"); //112
     ds.in_str_nazn = request.getParameter("destcountrycode");  //204
     ds.in_os_cond2 = 
     Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("specialmarkscode")); // по идее 58

    ds.in_svo_code = (short)Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dispatchtype")); // код вида отправки - нормально сделать

    ds.connectAppServer();
    JsonObjectBuilder js_ = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    if (ds.calcDistance()) {

        ParagrafService paraf = new ParagrafService();

        // выдача ответа
        js_.add("error", "");

        js_.add("out_joint_code", ds.out_vyh_styk);
        js_.add("out_joint_name", ds.out_vyh_styk2);

        js_.add("in_joint_code", ds.out_vh_styk);

        js_.add("bel_dist", ds.out_localDistField);
        js_.add("total_dist", ds.out_globalDistField);

        js_.add("paragraf", paraf.get(ds.in_st_nazn));

        JsonArrayBuilder js__ = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.distanceVector.size(); i++) {
            Station tempStation = (Station) ds.distanceVector.elementAt(i);

            JsonObjectBuilder js2_ = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            js2_.add("kod", tempStation.kod);
            js2_.add("name", tempStation.name);
            js2_.add("dorName", tempStation.dorName);
            js2_.add("dist", new Integer(tempStation.currentDistance).toString());
            JsonObject js = js2_.build();

            js__.add(js);
        }

        js_.add("route", js__);
        JsonObject js = js_.build();

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(stringWriter);
        writer.writeObject(js);
        writer.close();


        PrintWriter pw_ = response.getWriter();
        pw_.println(stringWriter.getBuffer().toString());

        pw_.close();
    } else { 
        js_.add("error", ds.ErrorMessage);

        js_.add("out_joint_code", "");
        js_.add("out_joint_name", "");

        js_.add("in_joint_code", "");

        js_.add("bel_dist", "");
        js_.add("total_dist", "");

        js_.add("paragraf", "");
        js_.add("route", "");

    }
}
```

Servlet and front deployed on different servers. The Apache Tomcat have CORS on. In console (browser dev tools)  the error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gbsapod/sapodbridge/getRoute?
cont=0&foot=0&outstationcode=150000&des…
rycode=804&specialmarkscode=58&dispatchtype=1. 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 
'http://sapod_test.gbas.gomel.rw, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 
'http://sapod_test.gbas.gomel.rw' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but `http://gbsapod/sapodbridge/getRoute` doesn't look like a valid url.

Comment: The problem is exactly what is stated in the error message. Your server side code outputs an illegal value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It doesn't allow for multiple values

Comment: My sevlet code dont form value in Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but front see two headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response.